# How to UPDATE a new column to be the first word of another column

Tags: mysql

I downloaded a massive amount of rows (over 98,000) from the USDA about plant classification.

However, upon closer inspection it turns out they did not offer a `Genus` or `Species` column.

After some studying it turns out that the `Genus` is always equal to the first word in the Scientific Name and the `Species` is the second word.

I used the following query to pull up the correct information I want placed in the `Genus` column. But, I am stuck at how to UPDATE each and every row based on another column in that same row.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Scientific Name with Author` , ' ', 1 ) AS `Genus`
FROM `plants`
```

I would really like to be able to execute this query using only MySQL and not have to resort to PHP, which is my knee-jerk reaction.

Any direction would be appreciated, here is an example of the table below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UPDATE` is almost identical to the `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET Genus=SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Scientific Name with Author` , ' ', 1 )
```

Comment: I am trying to run this right now. I didn't notice before, but the table is so large, it seems my server is struggling with the update, and it has been running for the past 2 minutes.

Comment: ewwww, that's a shame :( That's the correct syntax for what you want to do, but as to how to speed it up - you may have to just wait it out since this is a once-off.

Comment: Yeah! You are right, thank you so much for your help. Patience is a virtue.